# mysql like query bring other alphabet results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter active records to fetch all 's' pages from database, all alphabet display without any issue.

But when we fetch result of 's'. it brigs all other 'j', 'b' results as well, its only confelect with s alphabet.

```
SELECT * FROM (`ci_pages`) WHERE `cat_id` = '1' AND `page_stitle` LIKE 's%'

        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('ci_page');
        $this->db->where('cat_id', $cat_id);
        $this->db->like('page_stitle', $list, 'after');
```

The above given query brings all s results but other alphabet result mixed in it.

Answer (score 2):

change your like method,

```
$this->db->like('page_stitle', $pagetitle, 'after');
```

where $pagetitle contains the value for the like method.

Comment: still brigs 's' list with other alphabets as well.

Comment: just type 'echo $this->db->last_query();' to display the query after the like